# Using TSNE to Visualize Clusters in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, data-analysis

I'm using TSNE to visualize my clusters but the output seems a bit strange. There are supposed to be 3 clusters but instead, there are 4 lines. Is there something wrong with how I'm visualizing them or is it the kmeans method itself? **How else can I visualize the clusters?**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ast
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

colNames = ['unixTime', 'sampleAmount','Time','samplingRate', 'Data']

data = pd.read_csv("project_fan.csv",  sep = ';', error_bad_lines = False, names = colNames) 

# changing data into list
data['Data'] = data.Data.transform(ast.literal_eval)

# Selecting the average value from the list and replacing the list with it
data['Data'] = data.Data.apply(np.mean)

kmeanModel = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
kmeanModel.fit(data)

y = kmeanModel.labels_


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)

k = 3
tfs_reduced = TruncatedSVD(n_components=k, random_state=0).fit_transform(data)
tfs_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=40, verbose=2).fit_transform(tfs_reduced)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
ax = plt.axes()
plt.scatter(tfs_embedded[:, 0], tfs_embedded[:, 1], marker = "x", c = km.labels_)
plt.show()
```

Sample Dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APIG7C5d-zWPfe1bZa2azDmfQIkDOyVu/view?usp=sharing

```
       unixTime  sampleAmount  Time  samplingRate         Data
0  1.556891e+09         16384   340  48188.235294  1620.242170
1  1.556891e+09         16384   341  48046.920821  1620.237716
2  1.556891e+09         16384   340  48188.235294  1620.236340
3  1.556891e+09         16384   340  48188.235294  1620.229289
4  1.556891e+09         16384   340  48188.235294  1620.227541
```

My output:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jth9X.png
```

Comment: What about if you apply TSNE directly to your data and skip the SVD step? You don't need SVD here given your data has only 5 features.

Comment: @MaximeKan That still doesn't give an ideal result. I just get 4 different 'lines' (each with 5 different colored sections) instead of clusters.

Comment: You may think about providing a link to your data ...

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I added a link!

Comment: After tinkering with your data I can share with you not a solution -- as there is no solution here, I believe -- but several thoughts. (1) In general `TSNE` is not a very good tool for picking up a structure of your data. There are too many params in it. Varying them, sometimes you'll be able to discover the ground truth, sometimes not. You may try varying them yourself, or Google for examples, there many online sources. (2) Though not a good tool in itself, it can be useful as a preliminary feature extraction tool, as a basis for other algos (see Kaggle for model stacking)

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Thank you for taking out time for this! Could you suggest another way to visualize the clusters?

Comment: `PCA`, `SVD` or `TSNE` are the only methods of dimensionality reduction, that allow vizualization of n-dimentional data on 2D plane, I know of. BTW, `TSNE` is not too bad with its 4-6 clusters as your guess the ground truth is 3 is just a guess. It's just another opinion that should be tested through CV, if you have a ground truth.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at your code, and apart from perhaps playing with some parameters, it looks like your visualising things alright. Since t-sne is quite a dramatic non-linear transformation of the data, it's not always the case that groups found by clustering algorithms will also appear when analysed by t-sne.

I ran tsne (without the TruncatedSVD step for now) on the sample data you provided, and generated this tsne embedding plot.

[image]

It shows that the groups that appear in this embedding are largely composed of members of the same clusters assigned by K-means, which means there is at least *some* similarity in the groups that the two algorithms are proposing.

Is there a possibility that the ground truth of how many clusters may be in the data is not 3? Depending on why you decided on 3 for a value for 'k', you could look into validating this. The [Silhouette score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) and [Calinski-Harabasz score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabasz_score.html) are two examples of measures that can be used to evaluate the goodness of fit of clusters - you could run k-means with different values of k and use the scores to determine which value of k returns clusters that best fits the data (according to these measures). You could also try clustering algorithms that decide on the 'k' value themselves.

Finally, however, in terms of *other* ways to visualise the clusters, PCA, SVD or TSNE are the conventional methods of dimensionality reduction that I'm aware of. You could look into to investigating the different clusters by looking for (statistically significant) differences in their raw features/`colNames`.

Comment: You may think about increasing "k" in `KMeans` and see if both `KMeans` and `TSNE` agree better on cluster definitions (you may wish to check [sklearn.metrics.homogeneity score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html)). And actually there are 30+ methods to check goodness of your cluster definition. See `R`'s [NbClus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NbClust/NbClust.pdf)t library for a summary and realization. Defining optimal number of clusters is more of art than science and heavily depends on business logic behind